Facing this error while trying to create the QA build on android ->ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[armeabi-v7a] FAILED
C/C++: ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[armeabi-v7a]'.


com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MyProject\MyProjectUpdate\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android.cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2f3d4r3m\armeabi-v7a'
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/2] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/MyProject/MyProjectUpdate/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/2f3d4r3m/armeabi-v7a

C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe" ^
-C ^
"C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MyProject\MyProjectUpdate\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\.cxx\RelWithDebInfo\2f3d4r3m\armeabi-v7a" ^
reanimated
from C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MyProject\MyProjectUpdate\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android
ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 7m 28s
553 actionable tasks: 549 executed, 4 up-to-date
PS C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MyProject\MyProjectUpdate\android>
PS C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MyProject\MyProjectUpdate\android>
I am trying to create an QA build for to install the apk in the android devices. but is is not happing i am getting this issue. but the simulator build it is working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
